# earning by getting involved in Springsource projects

Tags: spring, open-source, springsource

Can one make any earning by getting involved in Springsource projects(by contributing code, submitting pull requests, testing features etc.)

Comment: why my question is being downvoted?

Comment: @Mat I see your point.  I think this is a reasonable question, but clearly not appropriate for stackoverflow.  Not sure of the appropriate place and simply marking this question to be closed is not constructive either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can if you are a VMWare employee.

You probably can (indirectly) if you are a normal guy. Being an opensource contributor is something good employers are looking for and may help you get a better job / salary.